# "Una de cal y otra de arena". ¿Cuál es lo bueno y cuál lo malo?

Tags: expresiones

"Una de cal y otra de arena" es una expresión que se usa con el significado de "una cosa buena y otra cosa mala". Por ejemplo,

> Mi relación con Paco es *una de cal y otra de arena*. Me da muchos disgustos, pero también me da muchas cosas buenas.
>
> En mi trabajo me toca hacer muchas guardias, pero me las pagan muy bien. Una de cal y otra de arena.
>
> Interpreto a un personaje bisexual en esa serie, así que me toca una de cal y otra de arena. ¡Puedo enrollarme con mucha gente que quiero y con mucha que no quiero!

La duda que me surge es: ¿qué es lo bueno y qué es lo malo en esta expresión? ¿Qué uso en cada caso si quiero enfatizar que algo tiene más de bueno que de malo (o viceversa)? Por ejemplo:

> Mi relación con Paco siempre es *una de cal y otra de arena*. Me da muchos disgustos, pero también me da muchas cosas buenas. Aunque si lo pienso, hay más de cal que de arena (¿o más de arena que de cal?) porque los disgustos superan a las cosas buenas.
>
> En mi trabajo me toca hacer muchas guardias, pero me las pagan muy bien. Una de cal y otra de arena. Aunque con más de cal que de arena (¿o más de arena que de cal?) porque últimamente me las pagan por hacer casi nada.

Investigando por Internet no he encontrado casi nada. Pensaba que iba a ser fácil encontrar cosas como "la cal es abrasiva" (es "lo malo") o "la cal es imprescindible para la argamasa porque la arena sola no puede bla, bla, bla" (sería entonces lo bueno), pero no he encontrado nada al respecto. En el mejor de los casos todo lo que he encontrado es algo como "ambas son imprescindibles" o "la expresión o hace mención a algo negativo o positivo, sino distinto/complementario".

En la expresión "una de cal y otra de arena", ¿qué es lo bueno y qué lo malo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Además de la expresión completa "dar una de cal y una de arena*, también es usual la parcial *dar la de cal*, que hace referencia a este dicho. Así que solo necesitamos conocer el significado de esta última expresión para saber cuál es la buena y cual la mala.

Pues bien, [buscando en Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dar%20la%20de%20cal%22) parece que la mayoría opina que la buena es la cal, pero no hay unanimidad. Así, vemos noticias deportivas como:

[El Mérida quiere al fin dar `la de cal´ en su casa](https://www.elperiodicoextremadura.com/noticias/deportes/merida-quiere-fin-dar-la-cal-casa_324147.html); obviamente, el Mérida quiere ganar.

[Unicaja gana al Cajasol y vuelve a dar la de cal](https://www.marca.com/2014/02/16/baloncesto/acb/1392581396.html); es decir, Unicaja vuelve a tener una buena actuación.

Pero también tenemos, aunque en menor medida, otras como:

[El Atlético Valladolid vuelve a dar la de cal en Guadalajara](https://www.noticiascyl.com/valladolid/deportes-valladolid/2017/03/04/el-atletico-valladolid-vuelve-a-dar-la-de-cal-en-guadalajara/); y en la narración vemos que el Atlético Valladolid ha perdido su partido en Guadalajara.

Por último, una noticia que usa las dos expresiones por separado (*dar la de cal* y *dar la de arena*):

[El Femenino da la de arena frente al Joventut Almassora (0-2)](https://www.diarioinformacion.com/elche-cf/2018/09/30/femenino-da-arena-frente-joventut/2068809.html); en el cuerpo de la noticia leemos que el Elche femenino había *dado la de cal* el fin de semana anterior, al vencer en Alicante, pero esta vez ha *dado la de arena* con una derrota en casa.

En conclusión: parece que el consenso general es que *la de cal* es la buena y *la de arena*, la mala; pero cuidado porque hay quien las usa al revés.

Answer (score 5):

Diego, no estás entendiendo bien esta frase.  Pon tú: imagina, vas a construir una casa con métodos tradicionales.  Quitas el pasto de una área bien horizontal de quizás dos metros de diámetro.  Sobre esta superficie que preparaste, con una pala, vas echando arena y cal en proporciones 1:1.  Luego mezclas los dos polvos, levantando los polvos con la pala por debajo y echándolos encima, hasta que tengas una mezcla homogénea.  Ahora haces un pozo en medio y lo llenas con agua.  Pones polvo en el agua y mueves la pala en círculos en la sopa.  Luego vas pasando el polvo desde abajo hasta el centro otra vez.  Vas caminando todo alrededor, repitiendo esta acción.  Ahora está lista la "mezcla" para pegar ladrillo sobre ladrillo.

En fin, *una de cal y otra de arena* es una receta para hacer la mezcla, y en la expresión simplemente quiere decir *una mezcla*.  "Mi relación con Paco es una de cal y otra de arena" significa que mi relación con Paco es una mezcla.  Eso es todo.

En lugar de "Aunque si lo pienso, hay más de cal que de arena," vas a tener que decir "Aunque si lo pienso, hay más de lo bueno que de lo malo."

Comment: Hacia el final tu respuesta se vuelve contradictoria. Hay una valoración para la cal y otra para la arena. No es simplemente una mezcla de cualquier ingrediente. Siempre que se usa esa frase, la implicancia es que se combina algo bueno con algo malo, algo fácil con algo difícil.

Comment: @Gustavson - Por favor, enséñame cuál parte se vuelve contradictoria.  No lo veo todavía.

Comment: En los dos primeros párrafos, dices que Diego no entiende bien la frase y que "una de cal y otra de arena" sólo hace referencia a una mezcla (de dos ingredientes cualesquiera). Pero luego, si no te interpreto mal, pareces atribuir distintas cualidades a los componentes, cuando dices: "En lugar de "Aunque si lo pienso, hay más de cal que de arena," vas a tener que decir "Aunque si lo pienso, hay más de lo **bueno** que de lo **malo**."" Tal vez no seas contradictorio y simplemente estés queriendo decir que "cal y arena" no son uno mejor o peor que el otro, pero en eso discrepo.

Comment: @Gustavson - Ah, gracias por explicar.  No es eso, sino que quise ayudar a Diego a expresar su idea, *Aunque si lo pienso, hay más de cal que de arena (¿o más de arena que de cal?).*  Por cierto, ¿podrías aplicar tu análisis a las frases propuestas por Diego en tu respuesta?

Comment: Aclarada la confusión. Observa, no obstante, que de usar "lo bueno" y "lo malo" se perdería el valor metafórico y el juego de palabras entre la cal y la arena.

Answer (score 4):

Yo siempre relacioné la cal con lo duro o lo negativo de una situación, y la arena con lo blando o lo positivo.

En [este artículo](http://www.lanacion.com.ar/1196532-para-memoriosos), el autor -- que curiosamente es ingeniero -- dice:

> La frase "una de cal y una de arena" hace referencia a cuestiones antagónicas -una positiva, una negativa-, mencionadas en sucesión inmediata. Según el autor, "en la mezcla de materiales de construcción, la cal actúa como aglomerante, en tanto que la arena es inerte". Deduce, por lo tanto, que "en los comportamientos humanos, la cal implica severidad, la arena suaviza las conductas".

Si bien la primera descripción dice "positiva" en primer lugar y "negativa" en segunda instancia, creo que el autor alude a las propiedades de ambos materiales -- activo el primero, inactivo el segundo. En una situación humana o social, recibir "una de cal" implica más exigencia, y es por lo tanto más problemático, que recibir "una de arena".

Sin embargo, [esta otra fuente](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=LWhNQamCRE8C&pg=PA117&dq=%22una%20de%20cal%20y%20una%20de%20arena%22&hl=es-419&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22una%20de%20cal%20y%20una%20de%20arena%22&f=false) lo plantea de manera diversa, contraponiendo a la fineza de la cal la aspereza de la arena.

Conclusión: *arena* y *cal* son claramente opuestos, gruesa e inactiva la primera, fina y activa la segunda. Para definir las bondades o defectos de uno u otro componente, todo parece depender de con qué relacionemos la positividad y la negatividad, si con la mera textura o con la capacidad de originar una reacción.

Nota: Mi valoración de la cal y la arena parece estar en línea con el orden en que Diego plantea las alternativas:

- Mi relación con Paco es una de (A) cal y otra de (B) arena. Me da (A) muchos disgustos, pero también me da (B) muchas cosas buenas.
- En mi trabajo me toca hacer (A) muchas guardias, pero me las (B) pagan muy bien. Una de (A) cal y otra de (B) arena.

Comment: ¡Interesante!  Para agregar una tercera manera de comparar esto dos ingredientes: la cal es más cara que la arena.  Me imagino que se podría usar pura cal para pegar ladrillos; en combinación con la arena, se gasta menos.

Comment: @aparente001 A la cal le faltaría cuerpo. Un consejo: nunca te dediques a la albañilería. :)

Comment: ¿Y la proporción uno a uno es la única que funciona bien? // Trabajé de ayudante de albañil por un tiempo años atrás.

Comment: @aparente001 Falta el cemento o concreto...

Comment: Ah, sí, gracias.  Creo que eso también sale más caro que la arena. // Sospecho que tu respuesta será la correcta.  Gracias por agregar ejemplos.  ¿Tienes acaso un error en el primer ejemplo?  Veo A, B, B, B.

Answer (score 3):

Pienso que **la frase no busca resaltar ni ponderar la bondad/maldad relativa de una cosa sobre otra, sino consignar cualidades distintas, la existencia de elementos de diferente naturaleza que se intercalan**, o ponen en juego en algún caso.

De ahí que el lugar común de referir metaforicamente
algo con el uso de la expresión `"una de cal y una de arena"` lo que hace es registrar las acciones o elementos de características opuestas, que se suceden en algún equilibrio o proporción, más o menos intercaladamente.

La consabida frase más que nada (interpreto) funciona para dar cuenta de una alternancia; intenta pintar una  dualidad de respuestas recibidas o situaciones observadas. La metáfora acaba allí, y quizás es apta precisamente por ser deliberadamente relativa e imprecisa, sin necesidad de que los atributos sean caracterizados como buenos o malos, porque, —como mayormente pasa— no es facil pronunciarse con un juicio valorativo definitorio de estos, cuando, en realidad, lo único que se quiere subrayar es la variación.

Es común en muchos casos ver esta ambiguedad interpretativa, para la cual la frase opera como una [descripción](https://dle.rae.es/describir?m=form) (= definicion imperfecta) que funcione sin un juicio taxativo de valor. Algo que no siempre hace falta, con lo que el dicho resulta suficientamente ilustrativo para, **unicamente consignar, dijimos, la alternancia, el contraste de elementos en juego**.

Comment: Ésta me gusta. El yin y el yang.

Answer (score 2):

Yo también he buscado por internet, y lo que he visto es que suponen que la mala es la cal, porque es dañina para el hombre...

Yo pienso que la cal sería la buena. La argamasa es más rica cuanta más cal lleve. Es la que reacciona con el agua, la que hace que fragüe la masa. La arena es el complemento. Podría ser grijo o canto rodado... o paja. La cal además tiene muchas aplicaciones beneficiosas por sí sola; luego está la cal hidráulica...
En la masa actual de cemento y arena, la cal sería el cemento; e igual que el cemento, la cal es más cara que la arena.

Yo soy albañil y, en referencia a la construcción, lo bueno sería la cal.
También, creo que es más lógico decir primero lo bueno en la frase, como en "un caramelo, un castigo"... Aunque esto es más, cuando se refiere entre parejas...

Esto no deja de ser mi humilde opinión.

Comment: +1.  Bienvenido, Pan.  Espero que encuentres más cosas interesantes por estos lados.

Comment: Gracias!!! Seguro q si

Answer (score 2):

No existe "la buena" en mi modesta opinión. Creo que "lo bueno" es que haya una de cada. El dicho alude a términos de proporción. Lo malo sería romper la proporción, desajustar el equilibrio.

Comment: La expresión se usa para indicar que una situación incluye aspectos positivos y negativos de forma alternada, no a que deba de haber un equilibrio entre ambas en dicha situación (como en por ejemplo "lo comido por lo servido").

Comment: Banco este tipo de respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

En México es raro el uso de "una de cal y otra de arena".

Lo que mayoritariamente se dice es "una de cal por las que van de arena", refiriéndose siempre a un desquite, en el cual, el agraviado hace pagar "todas juntas" (ya que se sobrentiende que han existido varias malas pasadas anteriores) al agraviador. Creo que esto complica la cuestión en lugar de aclararla.

En este sentido, "una de cal" es positiva para el agraviado, "las que van de arena", negativas para el mismo, y todo a la inversa para el agraviador.

Answer (score 0):

La cal en la presentación actual tiene una consistencia similar al talco, un polvo tenue y que si se sacude, flota un rato en el aire, viene en bolsas de alrededor de 30 kg
Si se llenara esa misma bolsa con arena, es posible que pesara alrededor de 70 kg
En realidad se usan bolsas de menor tamaño para arena, pero, el que desea las mas baratas por volumen contenido, no es raro que opten por la de 50 kg
Por lo cual podría interpretarse, como una liviana la de cal  y una pesada la de arena

Answer (score 0):

Prefiramos la cal o la arena (según el contexto), la Real Academia Española hace que todos nos equivoquemos pues, en su diccionario indica que 'una de cal y otra de arena' se define como la "alternancia de cosas diversas o contrarias para contemporizar". La cal no es mala, es necesaria. Igual que el arena; pero ambas son muy diferentes en su composición...

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Como ya han dicho en otros comentarios, ambos elementos son necesarios y no hay uno bueno y otro malo. El significado original de la frase era que hay que ir variando, dando de uno y otro compuesto, y no como se entiende hoy de que hay una parte buena y otra mala. La expresión que sí refleja eso es "a las duras y a las maduras", donde claramente las duras es la parte negativa. Sospecho que los periodistas deportivos han tenido mucho que ver en ese cambio del significado original.