# Uso y origen de la expresión "pon tú"

Tags: modismos, expresiones

En [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22218/6915) que da @aparente001, leo la expresión "*pon tú*" en esta frase:

> **Pon tú**: imagina, vas a construir una casa con métodos tradicionales.

Y en una búsqueda rápida me aparecen otros ejemplos como [este](http://www.excelsior.com.mx/opinion/maria-luisa-mendoza/2016/11/05/1126391):

> Pon tú que eres parte de la corte rusa y tu familia es invitada a cenar al Palacio de los zares...

y como este otro:

[image]

Por el contexto creo que significa "supón" o "imagina". ¿Estoy en lo cierto? ¿Dónde se usa? ¿Qué significa exactamente? ¿Cómo se originó?

Comment: En mi caso la expresión viene de México.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ésta es una frase que invita al oyente a imaginar o suponer una situación, o da por cierta una suposición a modo de hipótesis; introduce una hipótesis no de la manera sintáctica habitual (*Suponiendo que… Supongamos que… Imaginemos que… Vamos a postular que…*) sino por medio de un imperativo. No sé qué nombre tiene esta clase de discurso, pero me recuerda mucho a esas traducciones de la Biblia donde se emplea el imperativo *¡mira!* casi como puntuación.

Según leo en [este foro](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/p%C3%B3nte-t%C3%BA.863626/?hl=es), en Chile se dice *ponte tú* también con el significado de "mira, he aquí que", pero por lo demás el significado es el mismo que el notado en la pregunta. En el diario *La Tercera* [encuentro](http://www.latercera.com/noticia/carlos-soto-no-idea-pagaremos-los-34-millones/) por ejemplo:

> *"No digo que sea una causa, pero **ponte que** se perdió una caja con un par de millones justificables allí."*

En España (o por lo menos en Murcia) [se usa](http://www.laopiniondemurcia.es/opinion/2017/03/07/huelga-educativa-pa/811329.html) el *ponle*:

> *"Ponle que te da un perrengue. Bebes agua sudando, o te comes un espárrago de bote en mal estado, y sufres una embolia."*

En Argentina decimos *ponele* (o *ponéle* con la tilde ortográfica que ya no es estrictamente necesaria). Se emplea muchas veces sola esta palabra, sin subordinada, con el sentido de "Supongamos que es así". Hay un *ponele* de esta clase en *Un tal Lucas*, de Julio Cortázar (1979). Después de una larga perorata de Lucas, el diálogo sigue así:

> *—**Ponele** —dice alguien—, pero frente a la coyuntura histórica el escritor y el artista que no sean pura Torredemarfil tienen el deber, oíme bien, el deber de proyectar su mensaje en un nivel de máxima recepción.*

Se dice también *pongamos* (como en la canción de Joaquín Sabina, *Pongamos que hablo de Madrid*) y hasta *pongámosle*, como en el tango *[Se dice de mí](https://www.letras.com.br/tita-merello/se-dice-de-mi)*:

> *Si fea soy / pongámosle / que de eso aún / no me enteré.*
>   *En el amor / yo sólo sé / que a más de un gil / dejé de a pie.*

En todos los casos hay una oscilación entre los dos usos:

1. El hipotético: "supongamos que", "imaginemos que".
2. El concesivo: "aceptando que", "dando por cierto que".

Hay un par de apariciones del *ponle tú* en Calderón de la Barca ([aquí](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/el-veneno-y-la-triaca--1/html/fef2abb6-82b1-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_2.html) y [aquí](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=FWPC3jw7u38C&lpg=PA440&ots=relme5rOZ0&dq=%22ponle%20tu%22%20calderon%20de%20la%20barca&pg=PA439#v=onepage&q=%22ponle%20tu%22&f=false)), que me suenan a algo así como un *OK*, una simple muletilla verbal, uso que no es muy diferente al uso concesivo que actualmente le damos.

Lamentablemente no sé si pueda responder de dónde viene la expresión. En algunas formas suena como un abreviatura de la forma correspondiente del verbo *suponer*, pero el pronombre *le* no va bien con esa teoría.

Comment: Y en España se dice mucho _pongamos_, como en la famosa canción de Joaquín Sabina _Pongamos que hablo de Madrid_.

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, también por estos lados. Jorge Drexler (uruguayo) le dedicó a Sabina una canción, *Pongamos que hablo de Martínez*. Añado eso y otro más a la respuesta.